# How to add another virtual IP to the network interface on an Ubuntu 22.04 server?

Tags: networking, server

How to implement this via netplan?

Add another “virtual” IP address to the network interface on the
server:

> write something like this in /etc/network/interfaces
> iface lo:1 inet
> static address 192.88.99.1
> network 192.88.99.0 netmask
> 255.255.255.0

I can configure the panel to listen to the address: 192.88.99.1, but I can’t reach this address when connecting a proxy

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer to  waltinator!